# Using Localytics on multiple platforms - separate app key?

Tags: android, iphone, localytics

I'm intending using Localytics (http://www.localytics.com) for an app which will be released on both iPhone and Android. My question is: Should I aim to use a separate app ID for the two platforms? I'd really like to just use one (so that all my analytics apply to both apps) but I notice that some things like "operating system version" just appear as a bit of a mess if I use the same ID for both.

There's nothing in their integration guide mentioning this - anyone have experience of this one way or the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work on the Localytics SDK team and I'm happy to help.

While there is no technical reason you can't share a single key, we recommend keeping them separate. In addition to having a combined list of devices, operating systems, app versions, etc, your users likely behave differently on each platform. Using a single key will make it more difficult to see platform specific trends in your app usage.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! One quick followup question: The app is actually quite simple and so users will really have similar behaviour on both. If I did use the same key for both (so I could get merged country/carrier/etc analytics), is there any way for me to filter the datasets to just iPhone or just Android when viewing it in the dashboard? I can't see it in the free version but I am wondering whether the pro version may have better filtering.

Comment: But to counter this argument, using a separate keys will make it more difficult to see platform agnostic trends in your app usage, no?

Comment: @Jeff Lopes: Hi Jeff, I'm trying to integrate Localytics. Could you please take a look at this question? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072845/localytics-push-notifcations-not-working